# Entity Model Issue: Not able to create model for one particular table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-model

While creating the entity model I am getting the following error .

```
Added the connection string to Web.Config.
Successfully registered the assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in Web.Config.
ERROR: Unable to generate model because of the following exception: 'Value does not fall within the expected range.'.
Loading metadata from database took 00:00:02.1203632.
Generating model took 00:00:00.8390920.
Writing out the EDMX file took 00:00:00.
```

All the tables are getting created but the BC_States table is not getting created.I can't understand why.

Answer (score 19):

I've just been investigating a similar issue.  It turns out that Entity Framework outputs additional error information in the `Messages` section of the `Error List` window in Visual Studio.

As you can see it's much more useful than the generic error that appears in the `Output` window.  This was crucial in helping me to solve my problem.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting this, it would've taken me a bit to look at 'Messages' since it should really be put in 'Errors' IMHO.

Comment: Agreed, I only looked after a lot of head scratching!

Answer (score 7):

The question is not readable but I found the similar question at [Ado.Net Entity Data Model Not Updating Correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/774645/).

As for me (I had the same problem) the issue was because of there was no primary key set on one of the tables.

Comment: That was my issue as well. Just altered the table and I can import the table just fine.