# Updating EDMX from SQlite-file fails in VS2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sqlite, visual-studio-2012, edmx-designer

In our project we use a sqlite and EF4.

Updating the edmx was no propblem under VS2010. Since using VS2012 there seems to be some kind of namespace called "None", which not appeared before. (see screenshot)

As you can see the tables could be read. But when clicking finish the designer hangs with mulitple messages of kind:

- The table 'tbl...' is referenced by a relationship, but cannot be found.

Also installed the latest System.Data.SQlite without any changes.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does the  show in Datasources in VS?
View the Model.edmx as XML (right click -> open with)
See if that give you more info.
[Stack Model Generation info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543971/ado-net-entity-framework-update-wizard-will-not-add-tables)

Comment: It tells me that for one table the PK is missing and will be generated by the tool. But this table never had an PK defined which may sounds weird :) VS2010 handled this without any issues

Comment: I have found that if EF can't find a PK in some tables it will not add them to the model..